# Google Glass GDK Hello World Immersion Activity

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

Steps, I have used to create my first `Google Glass GDK` App

`New Project` > `Application name, company domain` > `Next` > `Glass (Glass Development Kit Preview (Google Inc.) (API 19))` > `Next` > `Immersion Activity`

**ImmersionActivity.java:**

```
public class ImmersionActivity extends Activity {

    /**
     * {@link CardScrollView} to use as the main content view.
     */
    private CardScrollView mCardScroller;

    private View mView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);

        mView = buildView();

        mCardScroller = new CardScrollView(this);
        mCardScroller.setAdapter(new CardScrollAdapter() {
            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return 1;
            }

            @Override
            public Object getItem(int position) {
                return mView;
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                return mView;
            }

            @Override
            public int getPosition(Object item) {
                if (mView.equals(item)) {
                    return 0;
                }
                return AdapterView.INVALID_POSITION;
            }
        });
        // Handle the TAP event.
        mCardScroller.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                // Plays disallowed sound to indicate that TAP actions are not supported.
                AudioManager am = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                am.playSoundEffect(Sounds.DISALLOWED);
            }
        });
        setContentView(mCardScroller);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mCardScroller.activate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        mCardScroller.deactivate();
        super.onPause();
    }

    /**
     * Builds a Glass styled "Hello World!" view using the {@link CardBuilder} class.
     */
    private View buildView() {
        CardBuilder card = new CardBuilder(this, CardBuilder.Layout.TEXT);

        card.setText(R.string.hello_world);
        return card.getView();
    }

}
```

**Manifest.xml:**

```
    <activity
        android:name=".ImmersionActivity"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_glass_logo"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_immersion" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.glass.action.VOICE_TRIGGER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.glass.VoiceTrigger"
            android:resource="@xml/voice_trigger" />
    </activity>
```

**voice_trigger.xml:**

```
 <trigger command="SHOW_ME_A_DEMO" />
```

Now, what i have `understood`, we can `run` this app by trigger `voice` command "`SHOW ME A DEMO`", Is that right or wrong ?

And is there any way to run Glass GDK app on Android Emulator using `Android Studio` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now, what i have understood, we can run this app by trigger voice command "SHOW ME A DEMO", Is that right or wrong ?

It's correct. YOu can even configure this trigger and use [other commands](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/reference/com/google/android/glass/app/VoiceTriggers.Command).

> And is there any way to run Glass GDK app on Android Emulator using Android Studio ?

No you can't. Only Tablet, Phone, Wear (watches) and TV devices are available on the Android Virtual Device Manager.

Comment: so is there any other way to test GDK app ?

Comment: With a Google Glass Unit, yes

Answer (score 1):

> Now, what i have understood, we can run this app by trigger voice command "SHOW ME A DEMO", Is that right or wrong ?

yes you could run a app with the trigger set as `command = "Show_me_a_demo"`

But with this you are only able to run it from the speak menu. 
I would turn it into

`<trigger keyword="@string/app_name"/>`

you could use any keyword you want but with this it would show up in the application menu as well as on the speak menu. The name that would show would be whatever you named your app.

It would also be a good idea to add `<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.glass.permission.DEVELOPMENT" />`

to your manifest. To make sure the custom commands work

there are no emulators for the glass available as of now.